# Non-breaking space in menu link name

Tags: navigation

How to put non-breaking space into a menu link name in Drupal 8? I tried `&nbsp;` but it got displayed   literally.

Comment: What's the problem with just using a space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your theme so menu items can be processed as html

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK()
 * processes 1 nested level of menu items
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_menu(&$vars){  
  if($vars['menu_name'] == "main"){
    foreach($vars['items'] as &$link){
      $link['title'] = Markup::create($link['title']);
      foreach($link['below'] as &$nestedlink){
        $nestedlink['title'] = Markup::create($nestedlink['title']);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Alternatively** you can use css to make regular white space not wrap

```
.menu li a {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Of course you have to adjust css for your particular menu class

Answer (score 0):

Solution without code: On windows use the keyboard combination `alt 0 1 6 0`  (hold alt key while typing the digits on the numerical pad) for a `&nbsp;`. On Mac use `alt space`.

Free extra hint: use `alt 2 4 0` if you need to enter a `&shy;` soft hypen

Comment: This actually worked for me! Can't get much simpler than this. +1